# How to perform double sort inside an array?

Tags: python, sorting

I don't know the exact term exists for this type of sorting. Here is the problem - 
I have a class `foo`

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self,a1,a2):
        self.attrb1 = a1
        self.attrb2 = a2

    def sort(self):
        return self.attrb1
```

An array "bar" contain objects of type foo. I want to sort the array in descending order according to the two attributes. First by `attrb1`

```
bar.sort(key=foo.sort,reverse=True)
```

Then I want to sort the sorted elements within themselves according to `attrb2`. So for two elements foo1 and foo2 in the array we have -

```
foo1 > foo2 
if foo1.attrb1 > foo2.attrb1
elif foo1.attrb1 == foo2.attrb1
foo1.attrb2 > foo2.attrb2
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
bar.sort(key=lambda x: (x.attrb1, x.attrb2), reverse=True)
```

And you don't need to define `foo.sort`

Comment: Hi, sorry to come back into this topic but if we need to do the first sort using the reverse property but we don't need the reverse for the second sort, how could we do that.
For example, we want the first attribute sorted by decreasing integer values but we want an alphabetical order for items with the same value.. 
In the proposed solution, the reverse property is applied for all sorts executed on the list.

Answer (score 2):

You're using classes already so just implement `__lt__`:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self,a1,a2):
        self.attrb1 = a1
        self.attrb2 = a2

    # just for convenience in `__lt__`
    def defaultorder(self):
        return self.attrb1, self.attrb2

    # answers `self < other`, used by the sorting algorithm
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.defaultorder() < other.defaultorder()

bar.sort(reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort already do this if you have a tuple of values.
If you change the method sort to return a tuple:

```
 class foo:
    def __init__(self,a1,a2):
        self.attrb1 = a1
        self.attrb2 = a2

    def sort(self):
        return self.attrb1, self.attrb2
```

Then the solution is really simple:

> bar.sort(key=foo.sort, reverse=True)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it without lambda (which I personally don't like):

```
import operator 
bar.sort(key=operator.attrgetter("attrb1","attrb2"))
```

operator.attrgetter works like this:

```
a = foo(3,4)
b = operator.attrgetter("attrb1","attrb2")(a)
print(b) #  You get (3,4)
```